# Disable CSRF token on login form

Tags: symfony, authentication, csrf, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.0

I am using Symfony2.0 and FOSUserBundle, and would like to disable the csrf token on my login form.

I have disabled the csrf protection globally on my website in my config.yml:

```
framework:
    csrf_protection:
        enabled:        false
```

This is working well, there is no csrf field added to my forms.
However, this does not apply to the login form. On this form only, I get an "Invalid CSRF Token" error if I don't include the token in the form with:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />
```

How can I disable the CSRF token on the login form?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Because my client wants the login form to be validated no matter how long the user has been sitting on the login page. Besides, I personally don't think a CSRF protection is necessary for this particular website.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you just go to your security.yml file and remove the csrf_provider from the form_login directive, don't need to update the action class or anything.

Answer (score 29):

You can disable CSRF protection in your form class by setting `'csrf_protection' => false` in its options array:

```
class LoginType extends AbstractType
{
    // ...

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class'      => 'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User',
            'csrf_protection' => false
        );
    }

    // ...

}
```

In case you are using FormBuilder to create your form instead of an AbstractType class, you can pass the options array as the second parameter for `createFormBuilder()` like this:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($users, array('csrf_protection' => false))
        ->add( ... )
        ->getForm();
```

Comment: Problem is I don't have such a LoginType class. Should I extend the Symfony2 LoginType class just to set the csrf_protection property to false? Is there no simpler way?

Comment: Yes it helped me realize that I had to look into FOSUserBundle's SecurityController to set the csrf to false. I posted my own answer though with more details on how to proceed. +1

Comment: You should have mentioned you were using FOSUserBundle.

Comment: Or if you are using the createNamedBuilder() method inside the 4th parameter: $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('', 'form', null, array('csrf_protection' => false));

Answer (score 1):

if you're using FOSUserBundle, and you would like to disable CSRF protection only on the login form, there are a few steps to follow.

Step 1) Create your own user bundle & Security Controller file

In order to over-ride the SecurityController that is built into FOSUserBundle, you must first create your own user bundle.

So, create a file called app/src/{YourApp}/UserBundle/Controller/SecurityController.php
You should extend the original SecurityController class, and copy over the loginAction method

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController as SecurityControllerOrig;
class SecurityController extends SecurityControllerOrig
{
   public function loginAction(Request $request)
   {
   }
}
```

Within the loginAction method, comment out, or remove these lines:

```
$csrfToken = $this->container->has('form.csrf_provider')
        ? $this->container->get('form.csrf_provider')->generateCsrfToken('authenticate')
        : null;
```

Then make sure that nothing is passed to view for the CSRF token:

```
return $this->renderLogin(array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error,
        'csrf_token' => false,
    ));
```

Step 2) Disable CSRF checking in Symfony's firewall (security.yml)

Make sure you comment out the existing "csrf_provider:" line in security.yml:

```
firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                #csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
```

Step 3) Override the routing for FOSUserBundle's security controller (routing.yml)

In routing.yml, comment out these lines:

```
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
    options:
        expose: true
```

Add these lines below the commented-out lines:

```
#Over-ride the SecurityController of the FOSUserBundle:
fos_user_security_login:
  path: /login
  defaults:  { _controller: YourAppUserBundle:Security:login }
  methods:  [GET]
  options:
    expose: true

fos_user_security_check:
  path: /login_check
  defaults:  { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:check }
  methods:  [POST]
  options:
    expose: true

fos_user_security_logout:
  path: /logout
  defaults:  { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:logout }
  methods:  [GET]
  options:
    expose: true
```

Note 1: I've only asked it to use the loginAction method from your custom SecurityController. The other two methods go to the parent class (not sure if it makes a difference).

Note 2: You need the "expose: true" part! Otherwise, you'll get a JavaScript error from the fos js routing bundle.

That should do it!

Answer (score 0):

I had to [override FOSUserBundle's SecurityController](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.2.0/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md) loginAction where the login form is instanciated.

I replaced:

```
$csrfToken = $this->container->get('form.csrf_provider')->generateCsrfToken('authenticate');

return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.'.$this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.engine'), array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error,
        'csrf_token' => $csrfToken,
    ));
```

with:

```
return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.'.$this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.engine'), array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error,
        'csrf_token' => false,
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to deactivate CSRF protection for a specific form in Symfony 6 if you are using createForm method inside a Controller

```
$form = $this->createForm(LoginFormType::class, null,
[
    'csrf_protection' => false
]);
```